# PDFBox unable to generate images from a PDF file pages

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have been using PDFBox to split pdf files into images for a while now, but after updating to 2.0.19 I have started running into unexpected exceptions.

This is the stack trace of the exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at java.awt.color.ICC_ColorSpace.toRGB(ICC_ColorSpace.java:191)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.color.PDICCBased.toRGB(PDICCBased.java:350)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.getPaint(PageDrawer.java:335)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.getNonStrokingPaint(PageDrawer.java:708)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.fillPath(PageDrawer.java:808)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.graphics.FillEvenOddRule.process(FillEvenOddRule.java:37)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:875)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:509)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:483)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:156)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:269)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:321)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:243)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:203)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:190)
```

Here is the code that I have been using to split the file:

```
try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("updated_test.pdf"))) {
    PDPageTree pdPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
    PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);

    int page = 0;
    for (PDPage pdPage : pdPages) {
        String fileName = "demo" + page + ".png";

        File tempImg = new File(fileName);

        BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImage(page);
        ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, tempImg.getAbsolutePath(), 150);

        page++;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And here is the actual file that causes the issue:
https://stackoverflowuploads.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/updated_test.pdf

All help, ideas and advice would be greatly appreciated, if you have ideas about other solutions/libraries that can achieve the same results those would be very useful as well. Thank you!

Comment: I have removed the `itext` tag from your question because it's not about **iText**.

Comment: Does the same code works for this problematic file with your older version?

Comment: Did you create this file yourself or is it "from the wild"? This one has a "DefaultCMYK" ICC colorspace with N=3. (should be 4).

Comment: Unfortunately it's "from the wild" so we have no control over it, is there any way we could preprocess the file so that it works with PDFBox 2.0.19?

Comment: Difficult. If it is just one file, then open it with NOTEPAD++, search for "/N 3", and replace the "3" with "4". I'm thinking of making PDICCBased more resilient, then you'd have to work with a snapshot because it would take 3-4 months for the next version.

Comment: Thank you Tilman, I would love to use the snapshot version, I basically wrote a quick and dirty hack that did exactly what you suggested but in Java, I will probably just do a try catch as a retry mechanism. Thank you!

Comment: LOL that is very dirty. /N 3 may be correct for other files. I have created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4801 and will commit my change tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in [PDFBOX-4801](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4801) and a snapshot build is available [here](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.20-SNAPSHOT/) at the bottom.

It will be in 2.0.20, which is likely to be released in summer (hopefully).

The cause is an incorrect /N value (3) in the dictionary of a CMYK ICC profile. The correct value should have been 4. This results in the mentioned exception later. The [corrected code](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1875464) checks the ICC profile and corrects the value of the PCICCBased object.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, thank you [Tilman Hausherr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535646/tilman-hausherr), going from your comment I basically did what you suggested but in Java as a temporary fix until you have a chance to make the snapshot version:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("updated_test.pdf"));
File file = new File("updated_test2.pdf");

if (file.exists()) {
    file.delete();
}

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("updated_test2.pdf"));
int i;

long m = 0;
char prev1 = '-';
char prev2 = '-';
char prev3 = '-';
while ((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
    if (prev3 == '/' && prev2 == 'N' && prev1 == ' ' && i == '3') {
        fileOutputStream.write('4');
    } else {
        fileOutputStream.write(i);
    }

    prev3 = prev2;
    prev2 = prev1;
    prev1 = (char)i;

    m++;
}

fileOutputStream.flush();
fileOutputStream.close();

try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("updated_test2.pdf"))) {
    PDPageTree pdPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
    PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);

    int page = 0;
    for (PDPage pdPage : pdPages) {
        String fileName = "demo" + page + ".png";

        File tempImg = new File(fileName);

        BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImage(page);
        ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, tempImg.getAbsolutePath(), 150);

        page++;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thank you so much for your prompt help!